# How to split json value by comma

Tags: javascript, html, json

I’m trying to split this json object value by comma and display it individually in a span tag.

data.json

```
{"tag" : "Red, Green, Blue"}
```

HTML Output

```
<span>Red</span>
<span>Green</span>
<span>Blue</span>
```

I can’t figure out how to do it, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Also, [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). If you have an object or array, then you have an object or array, full stop. JSON format is a *method of representing an object in a string*, like `const myJSON = '{"foo":"bar"}'`. If there are no strings, serialization, or deserialization involved, then JSON is not involved either.

Comment: Small hint: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can use somthing like this

```js
var json = {"tag" : "Red, Green, Blue"}

alert(
json.tag.split(",").map(color=> `<span>${color}</span> `).join("")

)
```

Comment: Thanks! That’s exactly what I need!